# Python Pillow Gif Artifacts/Background

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

*Goal: Each frame in the end should have a whole sudowoodo. Anything not sudowoodo should be transparent in the gif (i'd be fine with white too). My end goal is to be able to recolor it, so i have to be able to distinguish background vs pokemon.*

I'm using requests to get the gif from a website and then pillow to get the frames. When I seek through the frames the artifacts (mostly background) is interfering with my disposal method. I use https://ezgif.com/split to check how it should look.

I put the frame, disposal method and boxes around the disposal extents for my collages to help see how it should stack (shown in the image below). I put, at the bottom, example code that will show the reconstructed frames.

So how do i correctly get the clean frames using pillow?

---

### Images

**Note:**

- For pillow frame index 4 gets a white line in the body and frame index 27 has green background. And multiple frames have missing green in the orbs/branches.
- For ezgif.com to see the picture i have posted you have to put 'Ignore optimizations', but the end photo i want is what is shown on the website option of 'Redraw every frame with details from previous frames'.

Gif used: https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/sudowoodo.gif

Pillow results:
[image: Pillow Extracted Frames]
Ezgif's results:
[image: Websites extraction]

---

### Code

> **Python Versions**
>   Python == 3.6.4
>   Pillow == 7.0.0
>   requests == 2.23.0

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from io import BytesIO
import requests

#Depends on the dispose_method and disposal_extent will process accordingly
def method_dispose(i, frames, previous_frame):
    # 0 PIL = Overlay and pass
    # 1 PIL = Overlay and return previous
    # 2 PIL = Erase Overlay
    new_frame = previous_frame.copy()
    current_frame = frames.convert('RGBA')
    new_frame.alpha_composite(current_frame, dest=frames.dispose_extent[0:2], source=frames.dispose_extent)
    if frames.disposal_method is 0:
        return new_frame, Image.new('RGBA', box=frames.size)
    elif frames.disposal_method is 1:
        return new_frame, new_frame.copy()
    elif frames.disposal_method is 2:
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(previous_frame)
        draw.rectangle(frames.dispose_extent, fill=(255, 255, 255, 0)) #fill white transparent
        return new_frame, previous_frame.copy()

# Goes through the frames and pastes them next to each other then shows
def simpleCollage(frames, num_images_width : int = 5, num_images_height : int = 10):
    width, height = frames.size
    compilation = Image.new('RGBA', size=(width * num_images_width, height * num_images_height))
    fnt = ImageFont.load_default().font
    for i in range(frames.n_frames):
        frames.seek(i)
        the_frame = frames.convert('RGBA')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(the_frame)
        draw.rectangle(frames.dispose_extent, outline=(255,173,0,255))
        draw.text((0,0), f"F{i}-M{frames.disposal_method}", font=fnt, fill=(255, 0, 0))
        compilation.paste(the_frame, box=(width * int(i % num_images_width), height * int(i / num_images_width)))
        if i == (num_images_width * num_images_height):
            break;
    compilation.show()

response = requests.get("https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani/sudowoodo.gif")
frames = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
simpleCollage(frames)

width, height = frames.size
all_frames = []
pass_frame = Image.new('RGBA', size=frames.size)
for i in range(frames.n_frames):
    frames.seek(i)
    disp_frame, pass_frame = method_dispose(i, frames, pass_frame)
    all_frames.append(disp_frame)

all_frames[0].save(fp="test.gif", format='GIF', save_all=True, append_images=all_frames[1:], optimize=False, duration=frames.info['duration'], loop=0)
simpleCollage(Image.open("test.gif"))
```

Some sources I used for disposal method:

- [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMVw.png): http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/animation_and_transparency.html
- [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgpgX.png): http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose
- [3]: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting bad image results from the repeated `.convert()`. To solve this `.seek(0)` needs to be put after a `.convert()`. So the resulting code should look like:

```py
for i in range(frames.n_frames):
    frames.seek(i)
    disp_frame, pass_frame = method_dispose(i, frames, pass_frame)
    all_frames.append(disp_frame)
    frames.seek(0) # <-- Added
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a fully-tested, fully worked out answer, but a work in progress I wanted to save and share as I have to go and it may be useful to anyone else looking at this.

You can examine the extent, disposal, delay and so on of the frames in a GIF using **ImageMagick** like this:

```
identify -format "%f[%s] canvas=%Wx%H size=%wx%h offset=%X%Y %D %Tcentisecs\n" treething.gif
```

**Sample Output**

```
treething.gif[0] canvas=58x66 size=58x66 offset=+0+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[1] canvas=58x66 size=58x66 offset=+0+0 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[2] canvas=58x66 size=49x63 offset=+7+1 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[3] canvas=58x66 size=55x47 offset=+2+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[4] canvas=58x66 size=56x64 offset=+2+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[5] canvas=58x66 size=56x64 offset=+2+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[6] canvas=58x66 size=56x64 offset=+2+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[7] canvas=58x66 size=56x64 offset=+2+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[8] canvas=58x66 size=56x64 offset=+2+1 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[9] canvas=58x66 size=54x65 offset=+3+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[10] canvas=58x66 size=54x65 offset=+3+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[11] canvas=58x66 size=54x65 offset=+3+1 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[12] canvas=58x66 size=45x58 offset=+7+6 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[13] canvas=58x66 size=51x58 offset=+7+6 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[14] canvas=58x66 size=55x64 offset=+2+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[15] canvas=58x66 size=55x64 offset=+2+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[16] canvas=58x66 size=55x64 offset=+2+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[17] canvas=58x66 size=55x64 offset=+2+0 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[18] canvas=58x66 size=41x53 offset=+16+4 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[19] canvas=58x66 size=56x60 offset=+1+4 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[20] canvas=58x66 size=19x61 offset=+9+3 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[21] canvas=58x66 size=43x54 offset=+8+10 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[22] canvas=58x66 size=43x47 offset=+8+10 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[23] canvas=58x66 size=50x61 offset=+1+3 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[24] canvas=58x66 size=51x61 offset=+1+3 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[25] canvas=58x66 size=43x50 offset=+7+4 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[26] canvas=58x66 size=47x65 offset=+10+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[27] canvas=58x66 size=50x65 offset=+7+1 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[28] canvas=58x66 size=47x64 offset=+3+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[29] canvas=58x66 size=56x64 offset=+2+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[30] canvas=58x66 size=58x64 offset=+0+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[31] canvas=58x66 size=58x64 offset=+0+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[32] canvas=58x66 size=58x64 offset=+0+0 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[33] canvas=58x66 size=37x59 offset=+15+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[34] canvas=58x66 size=48x63 offset=+7+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[35] canvas=58x66 size=48x63 offset=+7+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[36] canvas=58x66 size=50x63 offset=+7+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[37] canvas=58x66 size=50x63 offset=+7+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[38] canvas=58x66 size=50x63 offset=+7+1 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[39] canvas=58x66 size=52x65 offset=+1+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[40] canvas=58x66 size=57x65 offset=+1+1 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[41] canvas=58x66 size=57x65 offset=+1+1 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[42] canvas=58x66 size=53x63 offset=+1+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[43] canvas=58x66 size=54x63 offset=+1+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[44] canvas=58x66 size=54x65 offset=+1+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[45] canvas=58x66 size=55x65 offset=+1+0 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[46] canvas=58x66 size=56x65 offset=+1+0 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[47] canvas=58x66 size=44x54 offset=+14+10 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[48] canvas=58x66 size=44x63 offset=+14+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[49] canvas=58x66 size=44x63 offset=+14+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[50] canvas=58x66 size=44x63 offset=+14+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[51] canvas=58x66 size=51x63 offset=+7+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[52] canvas=58x66 size=51x63 offset=+7+2 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[53] canvas=58x66 size=40x31 offset=+14+3 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[54] canvas=58x66 size=52x55 offset=+4+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[55] canvas=58x66 size=52x55 offset=+4+2 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[56] canvas=58x66 size=49x51 offset=+1+6 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[57] canvas=58x66 size=56x63 offset=+2+2 Background 3centisecs
treething.gif[58] canvas=58x66 size=56x65 offset=+2+0 None 3centisecs
treething.gif[59] canvas=58x66 size=48x64 offset=+7+1 None 3centisecs
```

You can also insert the following line into your program after `draw.text((0,0)...)` to get a similar output:

```
print(i,frames.dispose_extent, frames.disposal_method)
```

Now all I need to do is compare the two...

I am still trying to see what has gone wrong - my suspicion is either:

- you need to add a mask to the line `compilation.paste(the_frame,...)`, or
- that `the_frame = frames.convert('RGBA')` is doing you a disfavour because GIFs are actually palettised and something is going wrong with the conversion.

You can also see the coalesced frames from **ImageMagick** on a red background:

```
magick tree.gif miff:- | magick montage -background red -geometry +5+5 -tile 12x miff:- montage.png
```

[image]

Comment: So your comment on the convert being the problem seems to be right. If i seek to frame index 19 and do `frames.show()` it displays correctly. I'm not sure how to correctly get each frame on the collage without using convert.